# Linq to select all Children in all Classes

Tags: c#, linq

I have a List of classes where each class has a List of students.

I need to get a full list of students, but unique on the `student.personid`

```
allPeopleUnique=   classes.Select(c=> c.Students.Select( persons ??)).Unique(student.PersonId)
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to use [SelectMany](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.selectmany.aspx):

```
var allStudents = classes.SelectMany(c => c.Students).Distinct();
```

If the student objects for a single unique student are not the same, you can use the [`DistinctBy` recipe from this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/489258/linq-distinct-on-a-particular-property). Or you implement `IEqualityComparer` like this for the student type:

```
public class StudentEqualityComparer : IEqualityComparer<Student>
{
    public bool Equals(Student a, Student b)
    {
        return a.PersonId == b.PersonId;
    }
    public int GetHashCode(Student s)
    {
        return s.PersonId.GetHashCode(); // or just `return s.PersonId`
    }
}
```

```
var allStudents = classes.SelectMany(c => c.Students)
                         .Distinct(new StudentEqualityComparer());
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want all the students - in a flat list with distinct values (personid):

```
allPeopleUnique =  classes.SelectMany(c=> c.Students)
                          .GroupBy(p => p.personid )
                          .Select(g => g.First())
```